# Get rid of a weird box on images in Chrome

Tags: image, css, google-chrome, border, border-box

I have a weird box showing up around my images in Chrome. There is an example here: http://ulrikhogrebe.com/projects/bbcme.html - if you open it in chrome, and look at the first image under the header image (black and white), you will see a border around it (scale your browser if you miss it). 
Tried border: 0; - but can't seem to loose it. Also, it's fine in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `img` tag has no `src`. You will not be able to remove this border with CSS.

The only way to fix this is to use the `img` tag correctly. You are currently setting a background image on the tag rather than using it as it is design with a `src` attribute.

Your current code..

`<img class="article__img article__img--full" src="" alt="">`

```
.page--bbcme .article__img--full {
  ...
  background: url("../img/bbcme/bbcme2_784.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  ...
}
```

Correct usage...

```
<img class="article__img article__img--full" src="../img/bbcme/bbcme2_784.jpg" alt="Image description">
```

If you for some reason need to use an `img` with a background image, you can use a transparent image as the source. A 1px x 1px transparent gif or png would do the trick.

Comment: Hi thanks a million uʍopǝpısdn. That was driving me crazy. Still learning the ropes, and sometimes I end up digging myself in to a deep deep hole of confusion.